# One half - ImageView must occupy 50% & the other half - 2 EditTexts & 2 Buttons must occupy other 50%

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I need to form a Layout in which I want to put an Image in the upper 50% of the screen & two EditText & two Button in the lower 50% of the screen, and also it should be device independent so that the view doesn't get disturbed on smaller or bigger screens, it works fine on minimum 3.2" HVGA device but everything goes overlapped if run on a even smaller device. Upon adding a ScrollView, it doesn't give you the desired output, here's my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.125"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.125"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.125"
    android:text="Sign In" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.125"
    android:text="Create An Account" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't have textviews but edittexts...

Comment: @Zoran Crap, my bad. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your layout needs to look like, pseudo code:

```
<Linearlayout - vertical
    <ImageView, weight 1 />
    <LinearLayout - horizontal, weight 1 
        <LinearLayout - vertical, weight 1
            <TextView, weight 1 />
            <Button, weight 1 />
        <LinearLayout - vertical, weight 1
            <TextView, weight 1 />
            <Button, weight 1 />
    />
/>
```

For the `TextViews` and `Buttons`, make sure you set width to `match_parent`. For the `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`, make sure you set height and width to `0dp`.

Comment: I even have buttons, what about those?

Comment: @DerGolem And that after adding ScrollView or without it?

Comment: Buttons below the textviews?

Comment: @RiteshPanjwani ... which ScrollView?